# How can I run some test cases with chrome and come with Firefox using C# mstest?

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest

There are total 10 test cases. I need to run some testcases with chrome lets say 1-3 and 6-8 test cases with chrome and 4-5 and 9-10 test cases with firefox.

The code in helper file is

```
static public IWebDriver GetWebDriverC(browserType brt)
        {
            ChromeOptions cOption = new ChromeOptions();
            cOption.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(cOption);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            return driver;
            
        }

        static public IWebDriver GetWebDriverFF(browserType brt, string url, string username, string password)
        {
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"path";
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            bool ele1 = AutoItX.WinExists("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]") == 1;
            if (ele1)
            {
                AutoItX.WinActivate("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]");
                AutoItX.Send(username);
                AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
                AutoItX.Send(password);
                AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
            }

            return driver;
        }
```

Username and password is different for different users.
There are multiple testcases in main file

```
[TestInitialize]
        public void initilize()
        {
           Webd= Helper.GetWebDriverC(Chrome); 
        }
[Priority(0)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void 1()
        {
}
[Priority(2)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void 2()
        {
}
     .
     .
     .

[Priority(10)]
            [TestMethod]
            public void 10()
{
}
```

There is only one driver in Test initialize that is chrome and chrome gets open before each testcase run. I want that when testcases run on the basis of some condition as mentioned earlier testcases run on the desired Browsers.
How can I achieve that using C# mstest?

Comment: You could split your test cases into seperate classes, one for FireFox and one for Chrome, and in the FireFox initilize use `GetWebDriverFF`. Alternatively, you could create the WebDriver in the test case instead of the initilize step

Comment: Look up Selenium Grid

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're setting the WebDriver in the `TestInitialize` step, so any tests within the same class will be using the same driver, in this case Chrome.

One approach would be to have separate test classes for FireFox and Chrome.

Chrome Tests:

```
public class ChromeTests
{
  [TestInitialize]
  public void initilize()
  {
    Webd = Helper.GetWebDriverC(Chrome); 
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void 1()
  {
  }
}
```

FireFox tests

```
public class FireFoxTests
{
  [TestInitialize]
  public void initilize()
  {
    Webd = Helper.GetWebDriverFF(Chrome); 
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void 1()
  {
  }
}
```

Alternative solutions would include:

- Having two WebDrivers in your test class, one for Chrome and one for FireFox, and then you can decide in you tests which driver you wish to use.
- Creating a new WebDriver instance in each test